# How to increase badge number from push notification using own php APNS server by swift?

Tags: php, ios, swift

Now I'm working on IOS app project by swift.
So I need to increase badge number every time when the server push notification to the device.
Right now it is always 1 badge no increasing.

This is my payload.

```
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
    'badge' => 1
    );
// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);
$messageId = $randomNotiId;
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is always one because you have put 1 as the value for badge.  The device displays whatever value you put in the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to save the badge number every time you push a notification and clear all if user sees them.

You need to upload value to the server when seen and then when you push a notification to that user you can retrieve how many notification he/she has and use that number + 1.

I think thats the best choice, but you can save the number with NSUserDefaults or something like that, but you will have a problem if the user remove the app and DLs it again.

Comment: That mean nothing to do with the app just have to create some DB on the server?

Comment: @Norolimba. Its not that simple. 1) How is the server going to know if the user has viewed a notification? If the app sends a message to the server it can find out, but a user can view a notification without the app being launched. Its no good incrementing a count every time a push is sent as the push may not get delivered to the device therefore the count will be invalid 2) How will the app know if the user has cleared all the notifications? It has no way of finding this out.

Comment: 1)Yes, everytime the user sees a notification you need to queue a notification to the server to update the number. If the user see a notification without launching it it doenst count, its like whatsapp, you can see notifications but the badge number is not changed until you launch the app and go to the notification. And how can a notification not being delivered? If the server fails then dont increase the badge number of that user, you can control all this things in the server side.

Comment: 2) You need to use ´ didReceiveRemoteNotification´ to handle notifications and use this to ensure use has viewed it, then upload a 0 to that user notifications.
Dont know if theres a better way, but in my case it perfectly works. BTW if you find a better solution just let me know :)